# File path from OFD not working with TagLib

Tags: c#, taglib

I want to select an mp3 file through an open file dialog after clicking a button and change the name of file to an already specified string. The problem is that when I insert the file path to the `TagLib.File.Create()` as a variable I get a FileNotFound exception.
Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    string location = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        location = ofd.SafeFileName;
        var target = TagLib.File.Create(location);

        target.Tag.Title = "it works";
        target.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
 location = ofd.FileName;
```

to get the complete file path, instead of

```
location = ofd.SafeFileName;
```

which give you the file name.

also best practice will be:

```
TagLib.File target = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(location) && File.Exists(location))
        {
             target = TagLib.File.Create(location);
        }
        else
        {
            //log or print a warning 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much dude!